# ViewPager get invisible after coming from navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, fragmentmanager

I have been developing an app which contain navigation drawer on main page and on main page I have an framelayout in which I am displaying HomeFragment.java which contain viewPager.
The problem is when I launch my application the HomeFragment.java gets called and viewpager works fine. But when I click Home but in navigation drawer which call HomeFragment.java then the view pager gets invisible. Here are my code.
Please Help.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.motomojoapp.R;
import com.motomojoapp.fragment.FragmentDrawer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

Toolbar toolbar;
TextView textView;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_white);
    setToolbar();
    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment(fragmentManager);
    if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    }
}

public void setToolbar() {
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title_white);
    textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.home));
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.notification) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class));
        return true;
    }else if (id == R.id.map) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MapActivity.class));
        return true;
    }

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}
private void displayView(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment(fragmentManager);
            if (fragment != null) {

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                // set the toolbar title
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
            }

            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment(fragmentManager1);
            if (fragment1 != null) {

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager1.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment1);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                // set the toolbar title
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_white"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.motomojoapp.fragment.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.motomojoapp.R;
import com.motomojoapp.customadapter.SlideAdapter;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private SlideAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager ;

    public HomeFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor11
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
        viewPager.setPageMargin(35);
        adapter = new SlideAdapter(fragmentManager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(adapter.FIRST_PAGE);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="34dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

SlideAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.motomojoapp.fragment.SlideFragment;

    public class SlideAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int PAGES = 3;
    // You can choose a bigger number for LOOPS, but you know, nobody will fling
    // more than 1000 times just in order to test your "infinite" ViewPager :D
    private int LOOPS = 1000;
    public int FIRST_PAGE = PAGES * LOOPS / 2;

    public SlideAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        position = position % PAGES;
        return SlideFragment.newInstance(Integer.toString(position + 1));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGES * LOOPS;
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return 0.93f;
    }

}
```

SlideFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.motomojoapp.R;

   public class SlideFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PAGE_NUMBER = "pageNumber";
    private String mParam;
    private TextView tvPos;

    public SlideFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static SlideFragment newInstance(String pageNumber) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, pageNumber);

        SlideFragment fragment = new SlideFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam = getArguments().getString(ARG_PAGE_NUMBER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slide, container, false);
        tvPos = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tvPos.setText("Page " + mParam);
        return root;
    }

}
```

Comment: In case 1 you have forgotten the `break;` , I don't if this is the problem but I just indicate it .

Comment: @Rahul have you got any soution for this?